# search jpg file name in folders and subfolders and copy result file names

Tags: directory, jpeg

I am trying to get all the jpg file names related to 1 product. e.g. this is the product name 37004378_TM search this in file explorer & copy all the result file names like

> 37004378_TM-99999999_01.jpg 37004378_TM.jpg 37004378_TM_B.jpg 37004378_TM_B3.jpg 37004378_TM_D1.jpg 37004378_TM_D2.jpg 37004378_TM_D3.jpg 37004378_TM_D4.jpg 37004378_TM_D5.jpg 37004378_TM_D8.jpg

Tried a lot of things and already.

```
Sub jec()
Dim xp As String, a As Variant
dim TargetAddress as string

xp = "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\37004378_TM*.jpg"
TargetAddress = activecell.value
xp = "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\TargetAddress*.jpg"
a = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c dir """ & xp & """ /b/s").stdout.readall, vbCrLf)
Cells(1).Resize(UBound(a)) = Application.Transpose(a)
End Sub
```

I tried this it's very slow and I have a list 150 images. It's not working with variable

Comment: You should really tag the language you're using. Some sort of VB? Nobody will find it if you just tag `directory` and `jpeg`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.